# If the tag <input type='number'...> is used will the browser reject non-numeric input?

Tags: html

Will setting the input type to 'number' mean the browser itself will check for and reject any non-numeric input in this field before  submitting the form?

Comment: It doesn't allow entering non-numeric inputs, but you have to take into account negative values, floating point values and values that contain `e`, which are all allowed. So it doesn't to any validation at all, it just forbids entering some values. You have to validate for yourself

Comment: Yes, it will. The best you can do in this case is to write a dummy HTML file and try it. This way it will stick with you. Mozilla web docs is a good source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: @RaulRene I see. I will just add validation for the set of accepted inputs then thank you.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Good idea, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not be validated by the browser.
You should do a server-side **and** client-side validation instead.
The server side validation will serve as a fallback if they somehow bypassed the client-side validation.